# Mock inner method which uses local variable as paramenter

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I've recently started using Mockito 3 + Junit 5 + Spring 5 and I'm writing some example tests in order to understand how Mockito works. I have a question about inner calls. So, I have a spring component `A` in which is injected some DAO component `someObjectDAO`. The `A` class:

```
@Component("aClass")
public class A {
   @Autowired
   private ObjectDAO someObjectDAO;

   public Long countRecords() {
       ObjectSearchCriteria search = new ObjectSearchCriteria();
       return someObjectDAO.count(search);
   }
}
```

I want to test `A`'s `countRecords` method. I've mocked and injected `someObjectDAO` like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration("contextConfFileSomewhere")
public class ATest {
    @Mock
    ObjectDAO someObjectDAOMock;

    @InjectMocks
    A aComponent;

    @Test
    void testCount() {
         ObjectSearchCriteria search = Mockito.mock(ObjectSearchCriteria.class);

         Mockito.when(someObjectDAOMock.count(search)).thenReturn(1L);

         Assertion.assertEquals(1L, aComponent.countRecords());
    }
}
```

But this way is incorrect, in fact `PotentialStubbingProblem` is raised.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'count' method:
    someObjectDAO.count(
    com.example.java.ObjectSearchCriteria@45cc6b13
);
    -> at com.example.java.A.countRecords()
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. someObjectDAOMock.count(
    Mock for ObjectSearchCriteria, hashCode: 204078646
);

Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
However, there are legit scenarios when this exception generates false negative signal:
  - stubbing the same method multiple times using 'given().will()' or 'when().then()' API
    Please use 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' API for stubbing.
  - stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test
    Please use default or 'silent' JUnit Rule (equivalent of Strictness.LENIENT).
For more information see javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class.
```

If I understand correctly the exception indicates that I'm passing an object different from the actual object used in the code under test, right?

So, how can I mock a inner method which uses a local variable as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to mock the call to `ObjectDAO.count` which has parameters. Instead of passing an instance of the expected parameter as an argument, you should use an argument matcher:

```
 Mockito.when(someObjectDAOMock.count(Mockito.any(ObjectSearchCriteria.class)))
    .thenReturn(1L);
```

Edit: You should probably never even want to "mock a local variable". Your goal is to test the system under test (`countRecords` method) without knowing implementation details. All you can do is mock the dependencies.

Comment: I didn't know about Mockito.any(), that did the trick, thanks!

Comment: I still get this issue when I try using an argumentMathcer